# Cordova Facebook Plugin - Graph API Version?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Cordova Facebook Plugin version 0.11.0 in my app:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Facebook will be deprecating the Graph API v1 by end of this month:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

I can't seem to find any mention of which Graph API it is using. Can someone please advise if the Facebook Plugin is compatible with v2.0 calls? If not, how do I upgrade it to support the changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you included, the plugin uses v3.21.1 of the Facebook SDK, which will target v2.2 of the Graph API by default.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is it also safe to presume that iOS 7 & 8's built-in native Facebook integration (the native iOS popup dialog to post to FB) will be using an updated SDK?

Comment: The native integration does not use the Facebook SDK.